# Handling Content Security Policy in .htaccess

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, content-security-policy

I'm getting error on browser console as `'Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://xxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/web_app_assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com".'`

I have following settings in .htaccess - `Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com"`

*We have Web view and Mobile view for same website. If website loaded through mobile browser, we redirect to mobile domain (Which is pointing to same website folder) and we load the mobile view only, That time i get above error in console, and CSS & JS does not load.*

Comment: No it is not, it is working perfect on web domain, but does not work on mobile domain once opened in mobile browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. As we were redirecting to the mobile version domain on mobile browser, the web domain name / base path were defined in config file. So after redirection it was trying to load CSS & JS files from web domain and not from mobile domain.
So we replaced the static domain name / base path (https://xxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/) to dynamic domain name ("https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) in config file, and everything worked.
Thanks.